# Why robust PCA is giving varying output and how to stabilize it?

Tags: r, pca, robust

I see that if I repeatedly try following 2 commands, the biplots remain the same:

```
pc <- prcomp(iris[-5], scale=TRUE)
biplot(pc)
```

and:

```
pc <- princomp(iris[-5], cor=TRUE)
biplot(pc)
```

However, if I try following code of robust PCA (taken from help text of ?princomp in R), the output biplot keeps varying:

```
pc.rob <- princomp(sdf, cor=TRUE, covmat = MASS::cov.rob(sdf))
biplot(pc.rob)
```

It is not just rotation or horizontal/vertical inversion of plot but actual relative directions of arrows and position of individual points relative to each other also change. I had expected a 'robust' plot to be more stable!

There is no problem in R code. It is running without any error or even warnings.

Why does the biplot keep varying and how can I have a stable, reliable biplot output for robust PCA? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The source of variation is in `MASS::cov.rob`: from one run to another, the returned covariance matrix is slightly different.

The default method for this function is `mve`, which is implemented in the C function `mve_fitlots`, the source of which can be browsed [here](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/r-base/2.8.1/_m_a_s_s_8c.html#a28bcd79cf6c6856328b5975cfc78604d). It makes calls to a RNG.

It seems that the solution for a reproducible result is to add `seed = 1:626` (for example; any vector of 626 *integers* can be used) to the call to `MASS::cov.rob`. However, this grants only reproducibility, not reliability.

Comment: Is 626 the best number to get a reproducible and accurate robust pca? Which method will u consider to be gold standard for robust pca?

Comment: @rnso 626 is the length of the Random seed vector, nothing else. Robust PCA seems to be a generic name for many different methods, and you should open a different question to address your last request. To obtain helpful advice, you should briefly describe your data, what you want to do with the PCA, and why you think classical PCA is not appropriate.